# Visual Force Page version Issues with NotesAndAttachments - relased in Winter 16

Tags: apex, visualforce

if I change the VF Page version to 36 -am getting error

Error Message " 'NotesAndAttachments' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Account "

Comment: It would help if you include your VF page code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CombinedAttachments` instead of `NotesAndAttachments`

So your code will look like

```
<apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

If you are using `relatedList` or if you are using Query then update that.